# How to clear the input history on Safari javascript console

Tags: macos, safari, development

I’m trying to clear the input history on Safari’s javascript console, but it always come back when I press the up arrow. I’ve restarted the entire browser multiple times, and I also tried using Command-K. How can I clear the input history so that previous things won’t come back when I press the up arrow?

Comment: Try using `clear()` as described in this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/clear